# “volumes 'type' is a required property” error with docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, yaml, mqtt

I have just started to learn how docker works and I have a problem with the yaml file when using docker-compose.

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  portainer:
    container_name: portainer
    image: portainer/portainer
    volumes:
      - portainer_data:/data
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"

  hass:
    container_name: hass
    image: homeassistant/home-assistant
    volumes:
      - /home/flory/home_assistant:/config
      - /etc/letsencrypt:/certs
    restart: always
    network_mode: host

  mqtt:
    container_name: mqtt
        container_name: mqtt
    image: eclipse-mosquitto
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - /home/flory/mosquitto/config: /mosquitto/config
      - /home/flory/mosquitto/data: /mosquitto/data
      - /home/flory/mosquitto/log: /mosquitto/log
    ports:
      - 1883:1883
      - 9000:9000

volumes:
   portainer_data:
```

I am getting an error as below:

services.mqtt.volumes 'type' is a required property.

Can someone please help me rectify this?

Answer (score 5):

Delete the extra spaces here:

```
volumes:
  - /home/flory/mosquitto/config: /mosquitto/config
  - /home/flory/mosquitto/data: /mosquitto/data
  - /home/flory/mosquitto/log: /mosquitto/log
```

So it looks like:

```
volumes:
  - /home/flory/mosquitto/config:/mosquitto/config
  - /home/flory/mosquitto/data:/mosquitto/data
  - /home/flory/mosquitto/log:/mosquitto/log
```